# Создание строчных матриц их преобразование в матрицы вещественных чисел с помощью функции Split

Tags: c++, c, массивы

### Задача:

Нужно создать матрицы `А` и `В` типа `char` размерностью `mxn` и заполнить их значениями наподобие

```
str1 = "1.1 -3.3 44.6"

str2 = "3.4 -44.8 5.0"
```

Значения вводить с клавиатуры, разделяя числа пробелами. Заполнять одну строку матрицы за раз. Затем строковые матрицы нужно преобразовать в матрицы типа `double`. Использовать при этом функцию `Split` для получения отдельных строк, либо возможности `cin`. Рассчитать выражение `С = ((А+В)^T)*(B-A)`

### Вопросы:

1. Что это за функция `Split` и как ее применить для решения этой задачи?
   Не могу найти внятного объяснения. Как в видео-уроках, так и на сайтах строки преобразовывают в `double` с помощью циклов наподобие

   ```
    for (int i =0; i< str1.length; i++){
        if (str1[i] != ' ') {
          string intermidiate += str1[i];
       }
         else {
         double dnum = atof (intermidiate.c_str());
         intermidiate.clear()
         vector <double> vec1.push_back (dnum);
         }
         // Для последнего числа строки
         double dnum = atof (intermidiate.c_str);
         intermidiate.clear()
         vector <double> vec1.push_back (dnum);

      }
   ```
2. Как будет выглядеть этот цикл for для двумерного массива?
3. Что имеется в виду под "либо возможности `cin`"?
4. `Т` - это двумерный массив, использующийся для транспонирования матрицы `(A+B)`. Как его реализовать?

   ```
             #include <iostream>
             #include <cmath>
             #include <vector>
             #include <locale>
             #include <stdlib.h>
             #include <string>
             #include <windows.h>
             using namespace std;

             int main (void) {
             char *locale = setlocale (LC_ALL, "");

             string str_a;

             cout << "Заполните первую строку матрицы А произвольными вещественными числами."
              << "В строке должно быть четыре числа. Разделите числа пробелами: \r\n";
              getline(cin, str_a);

              string intermediate;
              double dnumA;
              vector <double> vecA1;


              for (int i = 0; i < str_a.length(); i++) {
              if (str_a [i] != ' ') {
              intermediate += str_a [i];
              }
              else {
              dnumA = atof (intermediate.c_str());
               intermediate.clear();
               vecA1.push_back(dnumA);
               }
               }

              dnumA = atof (intermediate.c_str());
              intermediate.clear();
               vecA1.push_back(dnumA);
   ```

Comment: Имхо, вопросы по уточнению задания нужно адресовать автору этого задания.

Comment: @alexolut Задание понятное. Непонятно, как его выполнить. Одномерный строчный массив я смог перевести в double, а как аналогично сделать с матрицей не знаю.

Comment: Если одномерный смогли, то представьте матрицу как одномерный массив, склеенный построчно.

Comment: Можно подробнее? Мой код для вектора добавляю в после вопросов, спасибо.

Comment: Допустим, есть матрица из двух строк: (1,2) и (3,4). Объединяем, получаем (1,2,3,4) - одномерный массив.

Comment: Получается одномерный массив, содержащий одномерные массивы? Как обращаться к элементам такого массива?